# User Experience - graph and table

Tags: ux-field, guidelines, style-guide

[image]Does anyone know if it's a good UI -UX practice to add multiple select options inside a table?

Comment: Where is this screenshot from? Are the dropdowns really part of the table or is it more a showcase of dropdowns?

Comment: It is a showcase of dropdowns done by me

Comment: It is not per se an anti-pattern if that is what you mean. The context is what makes something an anti-pattern or not (even these that we unanimously declare anti-patterns because there is hardly any context that justifies the usage). To get a more helpful answer you should describe the context in which you want to use this table.